# Filtering tibble in R using a "rule tibble"

Tags: r, dplyr, filter

I have a rule tibble, which looks like:

```
library(dplyr)
ruleTibble <- tibble(A = c(30, 25, 27), B = c(40, 41, 22))
```

So every row means a rule so that similar matches need to be found in the following tibble:

```
set.seed(1234)
actualTibble <- ruleTibble[sample(1:3, 20, replace = TRUE),] %>%
  mutate(C = sample(1:10, n(), replace = TRUE))
```

Now, I would like to go through rules (ruleTibble rows) rule by rule, and all matches should be filtered to a separate tibble and this tibble should be put on a list. So in the end there is a list with as many elements as there are rows in the ruleTibble. And the elements themselves are subsets of actualTibble.

How this could be achieved effectively and efficiently?

In this example, every actualTibble row had a counterpart in the ruleTibble, but sometimes it can be otherwise: In these cases the rows are just omitted. The number of rules can also vary.

Comment: looks like you're looking for something like `left_join(ruleTibble, actualTibble)`?

Comment: also "this tibble should be put on a list" <- do you mean inside of an already existing list, or converted into a named list?

Comment: @Mark Converted into a named list, where each and every rule has their own subset tibbles as elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want a list, you can do something like:

```r
library(dplyr)
ruleTibble %>%
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
  left_join(actualTibble, by = names(ruleTibble)) %>%
  group_split(rn)
# <list_of<
#   tbl_df<
#     A : double
#     B : double
#     rn: integer
#     C : integer
#   >
# >[3]>
# [[1]]
# # A tibble: 4 × 4
#       A     B    rn     C
#   <dbl> <dbl> <int> <int>
# 1    30    40     1     2
# 2    30    40     1     4
# 3    30    40     1     3
# 4    30    40     1     6
# [[2]]
# # A tibble: 11 × 4
#        A     B    rn     C
#    <dbl> <dbl> <int> <int>
#  1    25    41     2    10
#  2    25    41     2     5
#  3    25    41     2     7
#  4    25    41     2     9
#  5    25    41     2     6
#  6    25    41     2     4
#  7    25    41     2     8
#  8    25    41     2     2
#  9    25    41     2     5
# 10    25    41     2     6
# 11    25    41     2     1
# [[3]]
# # A tibble: 5 × 4
#       A     B    rn     C
#   <dbl> <dbl> <int> <int>
# 1    27    22     3     8
# 2    27    22     3     3
# 3    27    22     3    10
# 4    27    22     3     8
# 5    27    22     3     3
```

I added `rn` to facilitate the eventual split; if you are certain that no two rows in `ruleTibble` are identical, then you can simplify this with:

```r
left_join(ruleTibble, actualTibble, by = names(ruleTibble)) %>%
  group_split(!!!syms(colnames(ruleTibble)))
# <list_of<
#   tbl_df<
#     A: double
#     B: double
#     C: integer
#   >
# >[3]>
# [[1]]
# # A tibble: 11 × 3
#        A     B     C
#    <dbl> <dbl> <int>
#  1    25    41    10
#  2    25    41     5
#  3    25    41     7
#  4    25    41     9
#  5    25    41     6
#  6    25    41     4
#  7    25    41     8
#  8    25    41     2
#  9    25    41     5
# 10    25    41     6
# 11    25    41     1
# [[2]]
# # A tibble: 5 × 3
#       A     B     C
#   <dbl> <dbl> <int>
# 1    27    22     8
# 2    27    22     3
# 3    27    22    10
# 4    27    22     8
# 5    27    22     3
# [[3]]
# # A tibble: 4 × 3
#       A     B     C
#   <dbl> <dbl> <int>
# 1    30    40     2
# 2    30    40     4
# 3    30    40     3
# 4    30    40     6
```

Comment: This works perfectly! It even adds elements for rules it cannot match anything against from the actualTibble!

E.g.
ruleTibble <- ruleTibble %>% bind_rows(c(A = 1, B = 2))

left_join(ruleTibble, actualTibble, by = names(ruleTibble)) %>%
  group_split(!!!syms(colnames(ruleTibble)))

[[1]]
# A tibble: 1 x 3
      A     B     C
  <dbl> <dbl> <int>
1     1     2    NA
...